# Why R doesn't write the text I want on my plot?

Tags: r

I would like to write on my plot the data source, but apparently my code isn't working and I cannot figure out why. Can someone please tell me what's wrong? Here is the full code:

```
plot(oil$DATE, oil$VALUE, t='l', main='Crude Oil Prices since 1986', xlab='Date', ylab='USD per barrel')
text(x = 2007, y = 20, 'data source: FRED')
```

and here is the output:
[image]

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you want text(x = 2007, y = 20, 'data source: FRED') instead of text(x = 2007, x = 20, 'data source: FRED')?

Comment: After the edit is this still a problem? Nothing seems wrong with this code.

Comment: @CactusWoman Damn! I'm sorry, typo. The code I wrote on the console was with x and y though. So it is not the problem.

Comment: Depending upon the data type of `oil$DATE` simply using `x = 2007` may not make sense in the plotting coordinates.  Do `str(oil$DATE)` and if it is a date object, you'll need to fix your x coordinate. See `?as.Date` and watch the `format` argument.

Comment: you can try `text(x = as.Date('2007-01-01'), y = 20, 'data source: FRED')`

Comment: @BryanHanson Yes, I have done some manipulations on the data frame before plotting data. More precisely I have converted DATE with as.Date so it is a date object. Now I have understood my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
plot(oil$DATE, oil$VALUE, t='l', main='Crude Oil Prices since 1986', xlab='Date', ylab='USD per barrel')
text(locator(1), 'data source: FRED')
```

The "locator(1)" will let you identify the place you want to place the text via mouse.

Reference:http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html